# Specifying the public key token in the manifest

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, manifest, executable

I have taken a manifest from one of the answers posted here in SO and embed it into my exe with small modifications. It works well. The manifest contains the following code

```
version="6.0.0.0"        
processorArchitecture="*"         
publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"         
language="*"
```

My doubt here is publickeyToken. I found in msdn links about the publickey and replaced the publickey with my certificates token which is extracted by Pktextract.exe. But am getting error once I add that extracted publickey. Is there any problem in using the above `publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"`. shall I use the same one..

or is there any other way to remove the publickeytoken attribute from my manifest??

Comment: Did you actually use signtool.exe to sign the executable?  The publicKeyToken and version number you are using are only appropriate for a Microsoft DLL named "Common-Controls".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That public key token value is for the V6+ versions of the common controls library, and is nothing to do with your app itself.
Assuming it's in the `dependency`/`dependentAssembly` block, leave it as is and all will be fine.

If it's in the main `assemblyIdentity` node then either leave it blank or specify your own public key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can edit the Manifest with [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/download.htm) (but not with the Demo Version)

Comment: There are of course several possibilities. AFAIK, when using mageui.exe, you can't edit the target, image, exe file directly, but an exe.manifest file

Comment: ya I want only an exe.manifest for configuring UAC settings. So can I generate a manifest using magui.exe ?? Is it the right way?

Comment: This is one way. If you are compiling the project (exe) then you can edit this in the compiler settings.

Comment: Just in case you want to investigate on this issue and retrieve details about Manifest programmatically: (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88363/Retrieve-the-Assembly-Identities-from-a-Manifest-u)